# How to edit a JSON file of a React production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

In my developer build I have a JSON file with one data, I want to be able to change that data in the production build. I used npm run build to make the build. And I can't find that JSON file. I'm  making this website for someone so I want to make it easy to change the page content by using JSON.

```json
// src/json/download.json
{
    "file" :  "download.png"
}
```

```js
This is how I get the json file
const file = require("../json/download.json").file

const filePath = "download/" + file;

const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <Link className="dcm0cujv48 abled" to={filePath} target="_blank" download={file}>
            <p className="fs-14 fw-700 wspwho0gps">
                <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt fs-14"></i>
                Download
            </p>
            <p className="yb08fmpwlp"></p>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if you are in developement or production

```
function isProduction(){
return process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
}
```

then in your code

```
const filePath = "download/" + isProduction() ? pathToProductionFile : pathToLocalFile;
```

then in your scripts you need to create another build scripts
with the flag "NODE_ENV=production"

Or
setup multiple `.env` files, check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
for example
`.env.local`

```
file=download.png
```

and `.env.production`

```
file=production-download.png
```

then in your code you can use

```
process.env.file
```

as a variable that holds the value of your file and will differ from local to production